# Javascript works in body but not in jquery side menus w/ no console errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, jpanelmenu

I'm using the jpanelmenu plugin, but this goes for the first four of the jquery side menus on this list. www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/side%20menu/

The scripts work fine in the body of the page. When I move the markup

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<input id="tags" placeholder="Search"></input>
</div>
```

of this autocomplete search

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Comedy",
      "Music",
      "Radio"
    ];
    jQuery( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });

</script>
```

to the side menu like this

```
<div class="menu-trigger-selector"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-G1THV0EXgLY/VQgWdKfzIvI/AAAAAAAAAJg/_AtOhuTN9JI/s28-no/hamburger-menu-icon.png" alt="Menu Button" title="Menu Button"></div>
<div id="menu-selector" style="display:none;">

<ul class="info">
<li id="about" class="noselect"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="faq" class="noselect"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li id="contribute" class="noselect"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="login-register">
<li id="login" class="noselect"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<li id="register" class="noselect"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="ui-widget">
<input id="tags" placeholder="Search"></input>
</div>

<ul class="podcast-list">
    <li>Main1
        <ul class="podcasts">
            <li>Sub</li>
            <li>Sub</li>
            <li>Sub</li>
            <li>Sub</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>

</div>

<div class="container">
...
</div>
```

it stops functioning. The input box shows up, but the autocomplete results don't. I'm using drupal, with a bootstrap subtheme, and I think this may be playing a role. I have to replace $( with jQuery( in every script because of some conflict that I don't understand. I'm loading the scripts in this order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../drup/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script src="../drup/misc/drupal.js?nmk3bg"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- <?php print $scripts; ?> -->

<!-- Navigation -->

<script type="text/javascript">

/**
  *
  * jPanelMenu 1.4.1 (http://jpanelmenu.com)
  * By Anthony Colangelo (http://acolangelo.com)
  *
* */

(function($){
    $.jPanelMenu = function(options) {
        if ( typeof(options) == "undefined" || options == null ) { options = {}; };

        var jP = {
            options: $.extend({
                menu: '#menu',
                panel: 'body',
                trigger: '.menu-trigger',
                excludedPanelContent: 'style, script',
                clone: true,
                keepEventHandlers: false,

                direction: 'left',
                openPosition: '250px',
                animated: true,
                closeOnContentClick: true,

                keyboardShortcuts: [
                    {
                        code: 27,
                        open: false,
                        close: true 
                    },
                    {
                        code: 37,
                        open: false,
                        close: true 
                    },
                    {
                        code: 39,
                        open: true,
                        close: true 
                    },
                    {
                        code: 77,
                        open: true,
                        close: true 
                    }
                ],

                duration: 150,
                openDuration: options.duration || 150,
                closeDuration: options.duration || 150,

                easing: 'ease-in-out',
                openEasing: options.easing || 'ease-in-out',
                closeEasing: options.easing || 'ease-in-out',

                before: function(){ },
                beforeOpen: function(){ },
                beforeClose: function(){ },

                after: function(){ },
                afterOpen: function(){ },
                afterClose: function(){ },

                beforeOn: function(){ },
                afterOn: function(){ },

                beforeOff: function(){ },
                afterOff: function(){ }
            },options),

            settings: {
                transitionsSupported:   'WebkitTransition' in document.body.style ||
                                        'MozTransition' in document.body.style ||
                                        'msTransition' in document.body.style ||
                                        'OTransition' in document.body.style ||
                                        'Transition' in document.body.style
                ,
                transformsSupported:    'WebkitTransform' in document.body.style ||
                                        'MozTransform' in document.body.style ||
                                        'msTransform' in document.body.style ||
                                        'OTransform' in document.body.style ||
                                        'Transform' in document.body.style
                ,
                cssPrefix: '',
                panelPosition: 'static',
                positionUnits: 'px'
            },

            menu: '#jPanelMenu-menu',

            panel: '.jPanelMenu-panel',

            timeouts: {},

            clearTimeouts: function() {
                clearTimeout(jP.timeouts.open);
                clearTimeout(jP.timeouts.afterOpen);
                clearTimeout(jP.timeouts.afterClose);
            },

            setPositionUnits: function() {
                var foundUnit = false,
                    allowedUnits = ['%','px','em']
                ;

                for (var unitID = 0; unitID < allowedUnits.length; unitID++) {
                    var unit = allowedUnits[unitID];
                    if ( jP.options.openPosition.toString().substr(-unit.length) == unit )
                    {
                        foundUnit = true;
                        jP.settings.positionUnits = unit;
                    }
                }

                if ( !foundUnit ) { jP.options.openPosition = parseInt(jP.options.openPosition) + jP.settings.positionUnits }
            },

            computePositionStyle: function(open, string) {
                var position = (open)?jP.options.openPosition:'0' + jP.settings.positionUnits;
                var property = {};
                if ( jP.settings.transformsSupported ) {
                    var direction = (open && jP.options.direction == 'right')?'-':'';
                    var translate = 'translate3d(' + direction + position + ',0,0)';
                    var transform = 'transform';

                    if ( string ) {
                        property = '';
                        if ( jP.settings.cssPrefix != '' ) { property = jP.settings.cssPrefix + transform + ':' + translate + ';' }
                        property += transform + ':' + translate + ';';
                    } else {
                        if ( jP.settings.cssPrefix != '' ) {  property[jP.settings.cssPrefix + transform] = translate; }
                        property[transform] = translate;
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( string ) {
                        property = '';
                        property = jP.options.direction + ': ' + position + ';';
                    } else {
                        property[jP.options.direction] = position;
                    }
                }
                return property;
            },

            setCSSPrefix: function() {
                jP.settings.cssPrefix = jP.getCSSPrefix();
            },

            setjPanelMenuStyles: function() {
                var bg = 'background:#fff',
                    htmlBG = $('html').css('background-color'),
                    bodyBG = $('body').css('background-color');

                var backgroundGenerator = function(element){
                    var bgs = [];
                    $.each(['background-color','background-image','background-position','background-repeat','background-attachment','background-size','background-clip'], function(i,value){
                        if( element.css(value) !== '' ) {
                            bgs.push(value+':'+element.css(value));
                        }
                    });
                    return bgs.join(';');
                };

                if ( bodyBG !== 'transparent' && bodyBG !== "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
                    bg = backgroundGenerator($('body'));
                } else if ( htmlBG !== 'transparent' && htmlBG !== "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
                    bg = backgroundGenerator($('html'));
                }

                if ( $('#jPanelMenu-style-master').length == 0 ) {
                    $('body').append('<style id="jPanelMenu-style-master">body{width:100%}.jPanelMenu,body{overflow-x:hidden}#jPanelMenu-menu{display:block;position:fixed;top:0;'+jP.options.direction+':0;height:100%;z-index:-1;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch}.jPanelMenu-panel{position:static;'+jP.options.direction+':0;top:0;z-index:2;width:100%;min-height:100%;' + bg + ';}</style>');
                }
            },

            setMenuState: function(open) {
                var position = (open)?'open':'closed';
                $(jP.options.panel).attr('data-menu-position', position);
            },

            getMenuState: function() {
                return $(jP.options.panel).attr('data-menu-position');
            },

            menuIsOpen: function() {
                if ( jP.getMenuState() == 'open' ) return true;
                else return false;
            },

            setMenuStyle: function(styles) {
                $(jP.menu).css(styles);
            },

            setPanelStyle: function(styles) {
                $(jP.panel).css(styles);
            },

            showMenu: function() {
                jP.setMenuStyle({
                    display: 'block'
                });
                jP.setMenuStyle({
                    'z-index': '1'
                });
            },

            hideMenu: function() {
                jP.setMenuStyle({
                    'z-index': '-1'
                });
                jP.setMenuStyle({
                    display: 'none'
                });
            },

            enableTransitions: function(duration, easing) {
                var formattedDuration = duration/1000;
                var formattedEasing = jP.getCSSEasingFunction(easing);
                jP.disableTransitions();
                $('body').append('<style id="jPanelMenu-style-transitions">.jPanelMenu-panel{' + jP.settings.cssPrefix + 'transition: all ' + formattedDuration + 's ' + formattedEasing + '; transition: all ' + formattedDuration + 's ' + formattedEasing + ';}</style>');
            },

            disableTransitions: function() {
                $('#jPanelMenu-style-transitions').remove();
            },

            getCSSEasingFunction: function(name) {
                switch ( name )
                {
                    case 'linear':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    case 'ease':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    case 'ease-in':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    case 'ease-out':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    case 'ease-in-out':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    default:
                        return 'ease-in-out';
                        break;
                }
            },

            getJSEasingFunction: function(name) {
                switch ( name )
                {
                    case 'linear':
                        return name;
                        break;

                    default:
                        return 'swing';
                        break;
                }
            },

            getVendorPrefix: function() {
                // Thanks to Lea Verou for this beautiful function. (http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/find-the-vendor-prefix-of-the-current-browser)
                if('result' in arguments.callee) return arguments.callee.result;

                var regex = /^(Moz|Webkit|Khtml|O|ms|Icab)(?=[A-Z])/;

                var someScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

                for(var prop in someScript.style)
                {
                    if(regex.test(prop))
                    {
                        // test is faster than match, so it's better to perform
                        // that on the lot and match only when necessary
                        return arguments.callee.result = prop.match(regex)[0];
                    }

                }

                // Nothing found so far? Webkit does not enumerate over the CSS properties of the style object.
                // However (prop in style) returns the correct value, so we'll have to test for
                // the precence of a specific property
                if('WebkitOpacity' in someScript.style) return arguments.callee.result = 'Webkit';
                if('KhtmlOpacity' in someScript.style) return arguments.callee.result = 'Khtml';

                return arguments.callee.result = '';
            },

            getCSSPrefix: function() {
                var prefix = jP.getVendorPrefix();
                if ( prefix != '' ) { return '-' + prefix.toLowerCase() + '-'; }
                return '';
            },

            openMenu: function(animated) {
                if ( typeof(animated) == "undefined" || animated == null ) { animated = jP.options.animated };

                jP.clearTimeouts();

                jP.options.before();
                jP.options.beforeOpen();

                jP.setMenuState(true);

                jP.showMenu();

                var animationChecks = {
                    none: (!animated)?true:false,
                    transitions: (animated && jP.settings.transitionsSupported)?true:false
                };

                if ( animationChecks.transitions || animationChecks.none ) {
                    if ( animationChecks.none ) jP.disableTransitions();
                    if ( animationChecks.transitions ) jP.enableTransitions(jP.options.openDuration, jP.options.openEasing);

                    var newPanelStyle = jP.computePositionStyle(true);
                    jP.setPanelStyle(newPanelStyle);

                    jP.timeouts.afterOpen = setTimeout(function(){
                        jP.options.after();
                        jP.options.afterOpen();
                        jP.initiateContentClickListeners();
                    }, jP.options.openDuration);
                }
                else {
                    var formattedEasing = jP.getJSEasingFunction(jP.options.openEasing);

                    var animationOptions = {};
                    animationOptions[jP.options.direction] = jP.options.openPosition;
                    $(jP.panel).stop().animate(animationOptions, jP.options.openDuration, formattedEasing, function(){
                        jP.options.after();
                        jP.options.afterOpen();
                        jP.initiateContentClickListeners();
                    });
                }
            },

            closeMenu: function(animated) {
                if ( typeof(animated) == "undefined" || animated == null ) { animated = jP.options.animated };

                jP.clearTimeouts();

                jP.options.before();
                jP.options.beforeClose();

                jP.setMenuState(false);

                var animationChecks = {
                    none: (!animated)?true:false,
                    transitions: (animated && jP.settings.transitionsSupported)?true:false
                };

                if ( animationChecks.transitions || animationChecks.none ) {
                    if ( animationChecks.none ) jP.disableTransitions();
                    if ( animationChecks.transitions ) jP.enableTransitions(jP.options.closeDuration, jP.options.closeEasing);

                    var newPanelStyle = jP.computePositionStyle();
                    jP.setPanelStyle(newPanelStyle);

                    jP.timeouts.afterClose = setTimeout(function(){
                        jP.disableTransitions();

                        jP.hideMenu();
                        jP.options.after();
                        jP.options.afterClose();
                        jP.destroyContentClickListeners();
                    }, jP.options.closeDuration);
                }
                else {
                    var formattedEasing = jP.getJSEasingFunction(jP.options.closeEasing);

                    var animationOptions = {};
                    animationOptions[jP.options.direction] = 0 + jP.settings.positionUnits;
                    $(jP.panel).stop().animate(animationOptions, jP.options.closeDuration, formattedEasing, function(){
                        jP.hideMenu();
                        jP.options.after();
                        jP.options.afterClose();
                        jP.destroyContentClickListeners();
                    });
                }
            },

            triggerMenu: function(animated) {
                if ( jP.menuIsOpen() ) jP.closeMenu(animated);
                else jP.openMenu(animated);
            },

            initiateClickListeners: function() {
                $(document).on('click touchend',jP.options.trigger,function(e){
                    jP.triggerMenu(jP.options.animated); e.preventDefault();
                });
            },

            destroyClickListeners: function() {
                $(document).off('click touchend',jP.options.trigger,null);
            },

            initiateContentClickListeners: function() {
                if ( !jP.options.closeOnContentClick ) return false;

                $(document).on('click touchend',jP.panel,function(e){
                    if ( jP.menuIsOpen() ) jP.closeMenu(jP.options.animated);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            },

            destroyContentClickListeners: function() {
                if ( !jP.options.closeOnContentClick ) return false;

                $(document).off('click touchend',jP.panel,null);
            },

            initiateKeyboardListeners: function() {
                var preventKeyListeners = ['input', 'textarea', 'select'];
                $(document).on('keydown',function(e){
                    var target = $(e.target),
                        prevent = false;

                    $.each(preventKeyListeners, function(){
                        if (target.is(this.toString())) {
                            prevent = true;
                        }
                    });

                    if ( prevent ) return true;

                    for ( mapping in jP.options.keyboardShortcuts ) {
                        if ( e.which == jP.options.keyboardShortcuts[mapping].code ) {
                            var key = jP.options.keyboardShortcuts[mapping];

                            if ( key.open && key.close ) { jP.triggerMenu(jP.options.animated); }
                            else if ( (key.open && !key.close) && !jP.menuIsOpen() ) { jP.openMenu(jP.options.animated); }
                            else if ( (!key.open && key.close) && jP.menuIsOpen() ) { jP.closeMenu(jP.options.animated); }

                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            },

            destroyKeyboardListeners: function() {
                $(document).off('keydown',null);
            },

            setupMarkup: function() {
                $('html').addClass('jPanelMenu');
                $(jP.options.panel + ' > *').not(jP.menu + ', ' + jP.options.excludedPanelContent).wrapAll('<div class="' + jP.panel.replace('.','') + '"/>');
                var menu = ( jP.options.clone )?$(jP.options.menu).clone(jP.options.keepEventHandlers):$(jP.options.menu);
                menu.attr('id', jP.menu.replace('#','')).insertAfter(jP.options.panel + ' > ' + jP.panel);
            },

            resetMarkup: function() {
                $('html').removeClass('jPanelMenu');
                $(jP.options.panel + ' > ' + jP.panel + ' > *').unwrap();
                $(jP.menu).remove();
            },

            init: function() {
                jP.options.beforeOn();

                jP.setPositionUnits();
                jP.setCSSPrefix();
                jP.initiateClickListeners();
                if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(jP.options.keyboardShortcuts) === '[object Array]' ) { jP.initiateKeyboardListeners(); }

                jP.setjPanelMenuStyles();
                jP.setMenuState(false);
                jP.setupMarkup();

                jP.setPanelStyle({ position: (( jP.options.animated && jP.settings.panelPosition === 'static' )?'relative':jP.settings.panelPosition) });
                jP.setMenuStyle({ width: jP.options.openPosition });

                jP.closeMenu(false);

                jP.options.afterOn();
            },

            destroy: function() {
                jP.options.beforeOff();

                jP.closeMenu();
                jP.destroyClickListeners();
                if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(jP.options.keyboardShortcuts) === '[object Array]' ) { jP.destroyKeyboardListeners(); }

                jP.resetMarkup();
                var childrenStyles = {};
                childrenStyles[jP.options.direction] = 'auto';

                jP.options.afterOff();
            }
        };

        return {
            on: jP.init,
            off: jP.destroy,
            trigger: jP.triggerMenu,
            open: jP.openMenu,
            close: jP.closeMenu,
            isOpen: jP.menuIsOpen,
            menu: jP.menu,
            getMenu: function() { return $(jP.menu); },
            panel: jP.panel,
            getPanel: function() { return $(jP.panel); },
            setPosition: function(position) {
                if ( typeof(position) == "undefined" || position == null ) {
                    position = jP.options.openPosition
                }
                jP.options.openPosition = position;
                jP.setMenuStyle({ width: jP.options.openPosition });
            }
        };
    };
})(jQuery);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {
var jPM = jQuery.jPanelMenu();
var jPM = jQuery.jPanelMenu({
    menu: '#menu-selector',
    trigger: '.menu-trigger-selector',
    duration: 300
});
jPM.on();
 })

</script>

<!-- Search autocomplete -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Comedy",
      "Music",
      "Radio"
    ];
    jQuery( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you set up demo/jsfiddle

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @ChipDean He already said in header NO CONSOLE ERRORS.

Comment: @Tushar I forgot I made this post! Still having trouble. The demo can be seen at http://www.podliberty.com/drup. The autocomplete search in the body is identical to the one in the side menu. If you type 'e', Comedy will come up in the body search, but not in the side menu search. Someone recommended I use $(document).ready(function(){

}); around the jPM.on function but that did not work.